# Returning Something As a Particular Type

Tags: java, generics

My IDE says there's an issue on the last line of code here (`Cannot convert from Class<Ix> to Ix`). How can it be resolved?

Here, `Package` is an interface where the method `provides()` returns a `Collection<Type>` of the types (interfaces) that the package provides.

`m` maps a type to a Package which provides the type.

I would like `Manager's get()` to return something of the requested type. In the example below, class `P1` is a `Package` that provides a bunch of interfaces including `Ix`. I'd like to be able to ask the `Manager` to get the package that provides `Ix` and return it as an `Ix`.

```
public class Manager {

  public HashMap<Type, Package> m = new HashMap<Type, Package>();

  public void register(Package p) {
    for(Type t : p.provides())
      m.put(t, p);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T get(T t) {
    return (T) m.get(t);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    P1 p1 = new P1();
    manager.register(p1);
    Ix ix = manager.get(Ix.class);
    // What do I need to change so that the method call returns p1 as an Ix?
  }
}
```

I realize that the ideas in this code seem silly. But I still would like to understand the issue and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code `manager.get()` should be called with a `Type` object, but you are passing in a `Class` object.  It returns a `Package` object, not an instance of the `Class` object you pass in.  Look at your `Map m`: if maps `Type` to `Package` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

**1) What do I need to change so that the method call returns p1 as an Ix?**

Well, to be blunt you really can't. You could try casting, but I'm pretty sure that'd throw all kinds of errors.

As far as making sure `get()` returns a variable of type `T`, you need to pass some *instance* of the desired return type to the method. The issue comes from the fact that you're passing a `Class` object to `get(T t)`, so it returns an object of type `Class`.

The parameter for `get()` just needs to be an *instance* of the desired return type.
Try: `Ix ix = manager.get(new Ix());`

That would fix the error your compiler is giving you; but I think you're approaching what you want to do in the wrong manner.

**EDIT:** I just realized you mentioned `Ix` was an interface - you'd need to pass a class which implements `Ix` to `get()` in that case, because you can't instantiate interfaces.

---

**2) I'd like to be able to ask the Manager to get the package that provides Ix and return it as an Ix.**

I think you're asking for the *superinterface* of `Ix`? As in what `Ix` implements? You wouldn't be able to store that in an `Ix` variable, at least not without errors. `Ix` can hold `Ix` objects and any subclasses of `Ix`, but not superclasses / superinterfaces.

If you just need to know what the superinterface of `Ix` is, I'd recommend using `instanceof`.

Comment: Hm. I tried `Ix ix = manager.get(new P1());` and also `Ix ix = manager.get((Ix)new P1());` but both return `null`. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your response. (Basically I'm trying to build something that will manage implementations of interfaces for my program. So I can hand the program one manager with one set of interfaces for "production" and another manager with a different set of interfaces for testing. Or depending on what's going on, one implementation can be swapped out for another.)

Comment: Sure, I'd love to help more. So `P1` is an interface or a class?

Comment: `P1` is a class which implements `Ix` (and possibly other interfaces `Iy` and `Iz`) and which explicitly declares that it provides `Ix` via the result it gives when `provides()` is called. .... I have a different version of the code that works but I'd have to say  `Ix i = (Ix)manager.get(Ix.class);` .... that is, I'd have to supply the class and also perform the cast which seems redundant. It would be nice to be able to have `get()` return something that doesn't need to be cast.

Comment: If `Ix` extends / implements `Type` (which I assume it does, considering your for loop uses Type), you can try changing the method header for `get()`: `public <T extends Type> T get(T t) ...`

Comment: public <T, t> t get(T t) { return (t) hashmap.get(t); } .... this works and I wouldn't have gotten it without your help. This also works: public <T> T get(Class<?> T) { return (T) hashmap.get(T); }